# Create multiple websites on one iis without domain names

Tags: iis-7.5

I have Test server with iis 7.5, and i need to create 3 different websites in it. because this  is a test server i don't have domain names yet for each site.
I know i have option to give each site different port like this:

**website1:** 33.200.11.22:80

**website2:** 33.200.11.22:8080

**website3:** 33.200.11.22:8090

but i wonder if there is any way that i can "fake" domain name for each websites so testers of the sites can access like it was a real live website with domain name say something like:

**website1:** fakedomain1.com

**website2:** fakedomain2.com

**website3:** fakedomain3.com

my first thought was to "fake" the domains in the Hosts file but hosts file can only accept ip without port so i can do something like:

**33.200.11.22 fakedomain1.com**

but not:

**33.200.11.22:80 fakedomain1.com**

any suggesstions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you create subdomains on your DNS server like test1.yourdomain.com?

If you don't want to do that, the hostfile option is the way to go. Just add the fake domain name also to the website hostheader and run it on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

SUbdomains, or a hosts file that resolves the names manually.

Subdomains - also possibly with your own DNS to a top level domain just for development - is likely the approach most people would take.